# Pre Screening - Time spent on technical Test

Tags: job-search, new-job, recruitment, new-hires

It seems recently it has become more popular for some companies to send pre screening technical tests to the candidates.
It seems like hard work for the candidates as they usually ask for several hours commitment, whereas it takes max 10 mins for them to review the code.

Most annoying are the recruiters who try to explain to me why it's a necessary step in the hiring process.

What would be the maximum time I should spend on doing that test? How should I explain them when they leave it vague regarding the time spending on the task?

Comment: "What is your opinion about it?" Opinion based questions are off-topic here; voting to close.

Comment: If you want the job, you need to jump through their hoops. Sadly that's the way it is. They've got something you want, they can demand you to do something they want

Comment: @PhilipKendall I rephrased it so it's not about an opinion of someone anymore.

Comment: @Draken it seems that requirement is asked only by small companies, hence want to check if I am right? I talk about asking candidates to do it before they even wants to have a brief talk with you about the role and also not companies that invite you and ask you to do the test at their office.

Comment: "*Would you do X*" is always off-topic. "*Is it a trend to do X?*" usually suffers the same problem as a question. There are other questions that cover "how much work is / how many tests are too much to ask of candidates?". VTC.

Comment: @PeterTree Your issue being? They get plenty of candidates applying for the job and having a pre-emptive screening to whittle that number down, isn't going to cause them any concern. If you don't want to do the work, don't, but it might limit your job chances. If you're not up to putting in the effort to pass these pre-screening tests, why would they want to hire you?

Comment: Related reading: [Testing as part of the interview process](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/) **///** [Is there a professional way to refuse a time-consuming programming task given as a test for a job?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32808) **///** [Given a 'homework' tasks on a job interview?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/) **///** [Are pre-interview “tests” common for frontend development positions?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60417)

Comment: Thanks @Lilienthal I simply don't like time wasters, especially when the tasks come via recruiters and I can't gauge how genuine is the request. I wouldn't mind to do something after talking to the company, but someone who just tell me company X might consider you and I know nothing about them it's a waste of time in my opinon.

Comment: @PeterTree Entirely understandable, but your questions as it currently stands isn't something this community can answer. I think asking something like "*What is a reasonable amount of time to spend preparing for a first interview?*" is in line with what you're wondering and could be on-topic here.

Comment: Actually, rereading your question and comment I think you actually might be asking something that's on topic. Can your question be worded as: "*Is it reasonable to ask candidates to spend time on an exercise / test before they've passed the first screening?*" You could even ask a follow-up to that as in "Can I push back against that / ask for a a phone interview first?"

Comment: Thanks @Lilienthal I rephrase my question. I don't use this community a lot, but think people should be a bit more tolerate here.

Comment: _How should I explain them when they leave it vague regarding the time spending on the task?_ -- Why do you need to explain it to them? If you set your own maximum at, say, 4 hours, then at the end of the time, you can decide what to do -- submit what you have and hope it's enough for them or just forget about them and withdraw your candidacy.

Answer (score 4):

These tests are designed to prevent the company wasting interview time on people who are not qualified. Having both written these tests and sat them, I can say that they are incredibly valuable. In fact, I would go so far as to say that they make the company seem more competent, professional, etc.

Comment: I would agree if I know about the company after talking to them, but if it comes from a recruiter and I don't even know I want to work for that small company why should I?

Comment: Well, because I assume that you want a job...

Comment: I learned my lesson about taking hours long test just to get an initial interview. I now just simply pass it with a message that states I do not wish to potentially waste hours of my time without knowing if I would even get a "first" interview. The only time I do these tests is when I first meet the interviewer, then get an idea if I like to pursue it and they seem genuine.

Comment: @Dan totally agree with you, but after not looking for a job for a while when you start looking again you forget how some companies/recruiters are time wasters.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the maximum time I should spend on doing that test?

You should spend no more than 1 hour, 48 minutes on the test. On a more serious note, that is a decision entirely for you to make based on how much you value your time and how much getting to the next round of interview matters to you.

> Most annoying are the recruiters who try to explain to me why it's a necessary step in the hiring process.

There is an easy solution to this: simply stop engaging with such "annoying" recruiters.

> How should I explain them when they leave it vague regarding the time spending on the task?

There is also nothing you need to explain here. You could simply tell them that you are willing to spend no more than a certain number of hours on their test. Be aware though, that they too could simply tell you they don't want to consider you further in the interview process.

While you probably have genuine reasons for your irritation with the pre-screening tests, you should also realize that the companies have their own reasons for those tests. You may not agree with those reasons, but if you want to work for such a company, you don't have much choice other than to follow their interview process. Of course, you could just restrict your job search to companies without tests that annoy you.